# Jar executables not showing up in windows 8

Tags: windows, selenium, windows-8

This might be a noob question but my Windows 8 does not show any jar executable files after downloading. For example, I downloaded Selenium server zip file, but the jar executable doesn't show up when I extract it. Same issue occurs with all other files. All I see is a META-INF files

Any suggestions how this can be resolved would be of great help.

Comment: Even when you extract using 7-zip?

Comment: yes, even then it doesn't

Comment: You would probably have to put a screenshot in your question because its hard to tell what your asking.